# Replacing an instance of a Bloc in a blocprovider

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm trying to find a way to create a new instance of a bloc and have it reflected in the multibloc provider.

currently I have the following :

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider<BlocABloc>(
              create: (BuildContext context) => _aBloc,
            ),
            BlocProvider<BlocBBloc>(
              create: (BuildContext context) => _bBloc,
            ),
          ]...
```

I'm then trying to create a new instance of BlocABloc and also BlocBBloc as :

```
generateNew(){
setState(() {
 _aBloc = BlocABloc();
 _bBloc = BlocBBloc();
});
}
```

I was expecting the build function to re-execute and new instance is used in the BlocProvider. However, I'm finding that the BlocBuilder is still getting states from the previous instance of the Blocs.

Is there a way to do handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the reason why you want to do this. But you can force `BlocProvider` create method to be executed again by using `key`. Here is an example how you can do it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutterblocrecreate/bloc_a_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  BlocA _blocA;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _blocA = BlocA(1);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<BlocA>(
            key: ValueKey(_blocA.state),
            create: (context) {
             return _blocA;
            },
          ),
        ],
        child: BlocBuilder<BlocA, int>(builder: (context, int state) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              Text("Bloc stat: $state"),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16,
              ),
              Center(
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Create New Bloc"),
                  onPressed: _generateNew,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  _generateNew() {
    setState(() {
      _blocA.close();
      _blocA = BlocA(2);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Zakir that works thanks! Just to provide some context I have a bloc that I'm providing in at the root which handles getting a users account information thats used throughout the app. However in one of the screen I'm giving the ability to select other accounts and I didn't want the original fetched account to be impacted (hence creating a new instance).

Comment: @user1012500 The better approach would be using get_it package and register bloc as **factory**. So it will create a new instance each time you call it in root (like: ```BlocProvider<BlocA>(create: (context) => getIt(), child: ...)```)

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue related to re-execute and creating a new instance. You need to use it like this:

```
  BlocProvider.of<BlocABloc>(context);
```

You can read [more](https://morioh.com/p/958dadf5d8c0).